# How to use TMemo for email message body in Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have a TMemo object with about 30 lines (some text, some blank lines) of text in it representing the message body of an email I want the application to send. In the code below I'm passing the text in the TMemo object to `IdMessage1.Body.Text` (Indy 10), but my resulting email message body appears that it's just one continuous line wrapped. I would like to see the spacing I have that contains some blank lines. If I copy the contents from the Lines parameter of the TMemo and paste it into a text editor I can see the CR & LF at the end of the lines.

Does the CR & LF get stripped off in this translation, should I be using a different component rather than TMemo for this, or am I passing the lines in the TMemo to the `IdMessage1.Body.Text` incorrectly?

```
IdMessage1.Body.Text := EmailBodyMemo.Text;
IdMessage1.ContentType := 'text/html';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TMemo.Text` property returns the entire content as a single `string` without any "soft" (word-wrapping) line breaks inserted between each line, only "hard" line breaks (explicit `CR`/`LF` characters).

Use this instead:

```pascal
IdMessage1.Body.Text := EmailBodyMemo.Lines.Text;
```

`Lines.Text` returns a `string` that has each line separated by `Lines.LineBreak` (`CRLF` by default on Windows).

Or better, use this instead:

```pascal
IdMessage1.Body := EmailBodyMemo.Lines;
```

Which is the same as doing this:

```pascal
IdMessage1.Body.Assign(EmailBodyMemo.Lines);
```